# How to overwrite log4j.properties in confluent zookeeper

Tags: docker, log4j, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

We are facing an issue that we are not able to overwrite log4j.properties.

Here is our code
Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
#RUN chmod 777 /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties
USER root
COPY ./log4j.properties /etc/kafka/log4j.properties
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ROLLINGFILE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=/var/log/zookeeper.log
```

Note :- We are using this confluent zookeeper 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you could copy a template file instead

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser ./log4j.properties.template /etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template
```

where

```
log4j.rootLogger={{ env["ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL"] | default('INFO') }}, rollingfile

log4j.appender.rollingfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingfile.File=/var/log/kafka/zookeeper.log
log4j.appender.rollingfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingfile.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true

{% if env['ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_LOGGERS'] %}
{% set loggers = parse_log4j_loggers(env['ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_LOGGERS']) %}
{% for logger,loglevel in loggers.items() %}
log4j.logger.{{logger}}={{loglevel}}, rollingfile
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't copy in a log4j file. This gets overridden at runtime with a Jinja2 template defined here - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/zookeeper/include/etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template

To set custom loggers, simply add an environment variable for `ZOOKEEPER_LOG4J_LOGGERS` to the existing image rather than creating your own

You should also use Docker logging bridges rather than force the process to write to a file within the container